# mySQL & javascript. Can't seem to UPDATE my database using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I'm fairly new to programming itself and I am currently trying to create a food reviewing website for my school project. Currently, I am stuck trying to get my javascript to update my data to my database in SQL.

We were taught to use a controller, model, routing and the db-connection to connect to our database. I will try to only put the codes that are relevant to my question in here. Hopefully, it will be enough to see what is going on.

(edit) I forgot to mention that I am supposed to use Postman to test that my codes are indeed changing the data in my database!

I still don't quite understand it still but here are my codes:

my models I have 2: `user.js` is first

```
"use strict"
class user {
    constructor(userID, username, password, email){
        this.userID = userID;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }


    //Get
    getUserID()
    {
        return this.userID;
    }

    getUsername()
    {
        return this.username;
    }

    getPassword()
    {
        return this.password;
    }

    getEmail()
    {
        return this.email;
    }


    //Set
    setUsername(username)
    {
        return this.username;
    }  

    setPassword(password)
    {
        return this.password;
    }

    setEmail(email)
    {
        return this.email;
    }

}

module.exports = user;
```

Next up is my `userDB.js`:

```
"use strict"

var db = require('../db-connection');

class userDB {

    changePassword(user, username, password, callback){

        var sql = "UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE username = ?"

        console.log("username: " + username + " Password: " + password);


        db.query(sql, [user.setPassword(), user.getUsername()] , callback);
    }

}

module.exports = userDB;
```

I have my controller as well named `userController.js`:

```
"use strict";

const User = require('../models/user');
const UserDB = require('../models/userDB');
var userDB = new UserDB();

function changePassword(request, respond){

    var user = new User();

    userDB.changePassword(user, request.params.username, request.body.password, function (error, result)
    {

        if (error) {
            respond.json(error);

        } else {
            respond.json(result);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = { signUp, deleteAccount, getAllUsers, changePassword };
```

I have my routing codes as well, this one is called `routeUser.js`:

```
"use strict";

const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

function changePassword(app){
    app.route('/userChangePassword/:username')
        .put(userController.changePassword);
}

module.exports = { userSignUp, userDeleteAccount, getAllUsers, changePassword };
```

And finally my `server.js` file:

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
//Controllers

const routeUser = require('./routes/routeUsers');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 8080;
var home_file = "/index.html";

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//User

routeUser.changePassword(app);


function gotoIndex(f, request, respond) {
    respond.sendFile(__dirname + f);
}

app.get(home_file, gotoIndex);

// Starts the Web Server
var server = app.listen(port, host, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Well done trying to format your code as code (so many people don't even try). In your case, you used the Stack Snippets feature, which is for **runnable** in-browser examples. I've converted those into code blocks (the `{}` button, or just indent four spaces), since the above isn't runnable in the browser. You haven't really asked a question above, though, and you need to narrow the problem down more. See: [mcve]. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think your setters should be something like this :

```
//Set
setUsername(username)
{
     this.username = username;//then call the save() method if require > kind of this.save()
}  

setPassword(password)
{
    this.password = password;//then call the save() method if require > kind of this.save()
}

setEmail(email)
{
     this.email = email;//then call the save() method if require > kind of this.save()
}
```

If you use an ORM (for persistence), you can able to have `save()` or `persist()` stuff; unless you need to implement the save() [or CRUD if you need] method yourself

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for replying. I have finally fixed my issue. I realized that the data that was not going through my controller which is why it didn't change the data within my database.

Comment: @Nicole: you're welcome, could you validate my answer as well?